# Use GPU in Matlab for 10 000 array

Tags: matlab, gpu

I wanna find extremum of some function. this function use array with 10 000 - 100 000 elements. All operation inside function with array written in Matlab style (for example `C = A * B, C = A .* B, A(C) = D`) without any cycles.
I also wanna use GA or SA - optimization for this function.

Can I acieve acceleretion with GPU?
I expect that I can because all array operation `C = A * B, C = A .* B, A(C) = D` should execute in parallel mode.

But is it so and is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 0):

Execution speed depends on the parameters of your CPU and GPU. You could easily compare this with

```
tic
C = A * B;
toc
```

and

```
gd = gpuDevice();
tic
aG = gpuArray(A);
bG = gpuArray(B);
C = A * B;
wait(gd);
toc
```

Comment: I haven't GPU now. So what result should someone expect in most cases?

Comment: @user2055505 As I said before, this is highly dependent on the GPU. But I think that the use of a powerful GPU can achieve a significant performance boost.

Comment: When timing on the GPU in MATLAB, you need to use `gputimeit` or `wait(gpuDevice)` to ensure that the work on the GPU has completed. `tic`/`toc` will not do that. I would tend not to include the time taken to transfer the data to/from the GPU since hopefully this is only performed once at the start of your algorithm.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it depends on GPU's memory and number of microchips. But GPU can accelerate only parallel computation or huge arrays. Is my array with 10 000 - 100 000 elements long enough to get acceleration with powerful GPU? I asked this question because GPU don't accelerate small arrays.

Comment: @ Edric You are right with tic/toc, I correct my answer. About time taken to transfer data to/from GPU - I considered single matrix multiplication, because I do not know how user2055505 will be use it.

Comment: @user2055505 You need to check the performance of your algorithm with a specific GPU.